# how to bind data to gridcontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding

I am trying to use LINQ to select data from database and bind it to DevExpress GridControl. I have succeeded yet though. here is my code below. It doesnt bind anything, how can I fix this???

```
public ucEmailList()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     ARYADA_EMAIL_DBEntities db_ = new ARYADA_EMAIL_DBEntities();
     var elements = from element in db_.TEST_EMAILS
                    where element.ID >4
                    select element;
     gc.DataContext = elements;

}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `DataSource`, not `DataContext`.

Comment: there is no datasource in WPF

Comment: Does this help you further? https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18490

Comment: that doesnt help. My question is about WPF, but your advices are about WinForm

Comment: What object does `gc` represent?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that. It is DevExpress GridControl

Comment: Oh.  That's odd.  Generally a control exposes a `ItemsSource` property for this sort of thing.  Try binding to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, you can just change one line:

```
gc.ItemsSource = elements.ToList()
```

`ToList()` is required because `elements` has yet to be calculated and the control does not like binding to it.

For reference, `elements` was defined as:

```
var elements = from element in db_.TEST_EMAILS
                where element.ID >4
                select element;
```

### Do you want to know more?

Later, if you are interested in the [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm) pattern for [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) I recommend this article:

- *[Implementing the MVVM Pattern Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx)*

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ItemsSource`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_ItemsSourcetopic)

```
gc.ItemsSource = elements.ToList();
```

Anyway this is poor idea. Why don't you use `ViewModel` that provides data from a database and bind it in a XAML to proper property of GridControl?

**EDIT - the way I would do it**

1. Remove the code from code behind that initializes `gc`
2. Provided you have somewhere in your XAML a `GridControl` you should also have its property bound:

   <dexp:GridControl //.... some properties
     ItemsSource={Binding Data} />
3. Inside view initialization (see point 1) set `DataContext` to you view model that contains property `Data` which actually gets data from a repository.
4. Make sure data are not directly objects from the database. Remap them to your Domain objects. To save some time you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: I dont know ViewModel. can you give an example

Comment: I used the ItemsSource and it gave me this error "Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported"

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ Check out _[Implementing the MVVM Pattern Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx)_

Comment: `gc.ItemsSource = elements;` should read `gc.ItemsSource = elements.ToList();`

Comment: @ARIFYILMAZ If you're new to this stuff, try reading something first. I would recommend for example this: http://www.apress.com/9781430243656